# Blue Prism How to write a collection in MS Word VBO

Tags: blueprism

I've got one problem. I need to write my collection which contains 50 rows into my MS Word file. 
How can I do it? I've checked that there is an action named Type Text, but it is only for text type, not for a collection. 
Could you please give me some advice ?
Best regards

Comment: Why not just extend the MS Word VBO and add your own functionality for writing collection data?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

1) Use a loop for your specified collection

2) Inside your loop use **Object MS Word VBO** and **Action Type Text**

3) In **text field** use the columns of your collection that you want to write to the  word file **(Example [Collection.Column1]&"-----"&[Collection.Column2])**

4) Use **Object MS Word VBO** and **Action Save As** to save your file

5) Finally use **Object MS Word VBO** and **Action Exit**

**Keep in mind that for the newest versions of Microsoft Suite you need to:**

1) Use **Object MS Word VBO** and **Action Show** for your files when you want to write some values (in your case Word)

Check the solution below:

[image]

Hope these information will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried your solution but it only writes the first row, not all of them

Comment: @Daenerys Please check your Loop Action and set there your collection you want to iterate, based on your process behavior you did not specify any collection. Please get back to me with your results.